# ssh.net not accept DSA key type

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I am using the nuget library of the SSH.NET, I am intend to do a SFTP connection to retrieve and upload data. However, I meet one problem which is I recieve an `Invalid private key file.` error.

This is my private key file string:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-dss
Encryption: none
Comment: dsa-key-20160523
Public-Lines: 18
AA         ------some key----------NAZiN8jDuiBte7MPV7
F6s=
Private-Lines: 1
AAAAFDfhoQV18cCh6cVFcNcvRoqdXPXI
Private-MAC: f06d16402bbe702c0f27bd43290e12c6954f02d5
```

This is my code:

```
var keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPKeyLocation"]);
var keyFiles = new[] { keyFile };
#region define sftp connection
var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPHost"],
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPUser"],
                new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPUser"], keyFiles));

var sftp = new SftpClient(connectionInfo);
```

How come I got invalid private key error? I can ensure this key is valid because it was successful to SFTP on other place.